# Using an empty keystore password used to be possible?

Tags: java, android, keytool

When signing an apk after a long break from Android development I was surprised that I'm no longer able to enter an **empty keystore password** to unlock it. Is it just me or has this been possible before? If so, when did that change and how can I manage to unlock the keystore anyway?

Some background: maybe I'm just crazy and didn't use an empty password for the keystore before, but the one and only possible password that I could have been using instead doesn't work either (I swear, there's no chance I'd have used another password!).

Comment: Is this a keystore you created, or is it the debug keystore? I am assuming that you mean the former, but I just wanted to check...

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yep, I created the keystore using ADT years ago...

David: It's "hitting-enter-instantly-empty" :)

Comment: maybe you mixed up the keystore? (happened to me and i found out after quite a while ...)

Comment: @dorjeduck: nope, it's the only keystore I have.

Answer (score 12):

The keystore can be manipulated using the `keytool` in the Java sdk.

Try executing the keytool on your keystore, and extract the certificates with the empty password. After that, import it into a new keystore. This time, use a real password.

The switch `-exportcert` will help you accomplish that.

It could be that you updated your java sdk and therefor you cannot enter empty password (due to some security upgrade of the tool). In that case, you can try to install an older sdk and do the above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Udinic, but keytool itself doesn't permit empty passwords either! :/

I guess it's an update of the Java SDK that changed it, too, but to be honest, I don't want to go through all SDK revisions of the last two years... :) Any tip what version might work would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't have to install each one, just take the one you probably had 2 years ago, and go along with it.

Comment: OK, try using "-storepass <password>" option of keytool to store a new pass. Backup your keystore before doing that.

Comment: @Udinic is there any chance that you can provide the steps to -exportcert to import into a new keystore? So the following will allow you to extract the information using the empty password "keytool -list -v -keystore [keystore-filename]", how do I go about exporting these into a new keystore? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use an empty password for your keystore.

I checked, as far as jdk 1.3 keytool does'nt allow it, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html where doc explicitely states that:

> storepass **must** be at least 6 characters long. It must be provided to all commands that access the keystore contents. For such commands, if a -storepass option is not provided at the command line, the user is prompted for it.

For fun, I wanted to try keytool from jdk 1.2 and downloaded it since its documentation doesn't state that password is mandatory, but I need a Windows NT box to install it!
I absolutely don't think Android ever used this keytool version.

Sorry, but it looks like you have either: forgotten your password, or typed it with caps locks / a wrong keyboard layout activated. :(

EDIT:

If it is not a layout problem you can try to

- Use this reverse engineered code to extract key using an empty string password: http://metastatic.org/source/JKS.java.
- If this doesn't work you are screwed, your only hope will be to brute force the key using http://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/ or http://code.google.com/p/patator/ (test and use the fastest one)

Comment: The link to keytool from v 1.3 is dead sadly.

Answer (score 5):

Try default android debug mode keystore password which is `android` or java cacerts default `changeit`/`changeme`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using keytool, you could write a simple Java SE program that tries to use your key or lists aliases. The API *should* (not a 100% on this) allow you to use an empty (`""`) password.

You can also try third party tools like [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to list/extract keys.

Comment: Tested, but portecle does not open old keystores with an empty password.

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue as well and it was very weird. I had a legacy keystore that was not protected by any password. I could use it successfully in SoapUI but `keytool` and [keystore explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/features.html) failed to open it. I had to create new keystore that already had a password and since then everything was fine.

I suspect that Java 8 is more picky that Java 7 was.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.jks -destkeystore client2.jsk -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass changeit
```

Comment: This still asks for the key password and doesn't accept blank

Comment: Better is to create a new keystore (jks) when we do not have JKS passwords or passwords of any entries within it.

keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA  -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=domainname, O=org, C=EU" -keypass changeit -validity 1096 -keystore "C:\Documents\sslcertificate\keystores\javakeystore.jks" -ext san=dns:domainname

Answer (score 3):

That works for me:

```
keytool -list -keystore keyStoreFileWithotPassword.jks -protected
```

CORRECTION: It turn out the **list** feature works without entering the actual password! But the **import** features do require a password

Answer (score 2):

I've just faced the same problem when trying to use the key store provider for hadoop, which uses `none` as default password, see: [JavaKeyStoreProvider.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/rel/release-3.1.1/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/crypto/key/JavaKeyStoreProvider.java#L100)

I ended up copying the original [keytool](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/keytool/Main.java) from OpenJDK8 and removed the restrictions in this new implementation (it is the same but without the 6 characteres limitation): [KeytoolWithoutPasswordLimits](https://github.com/gumartinm/SparkForFun/blob/01e9273ffe6a017971ed7ec035f9287dff98f872/keytool/src/sun/security/tools/keytool/KeytoolWithoutPasswordLimits.java)

In this way, I managed to use `none` as password.

Comment: AdoptopenJDK's keytool, from version 8 (lowest i can still download there) https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html - doesn't help either. Same error regarding the minimum 6 characters

Keytoolwithoutpasswordlimits does not compile on it's own - some more info (or at least instructions how you would compile the base .java file) would be greatly appreciated, though i suspect it's "download openjdk, extract src.zip, javac <filename>".

javac -XDignore.symbol.file - is needed, and some tinkering to the source file - should be worth adding in the answer.

Comment: @T.S For example, with IntelliJ, you could create a new Java application following these [steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html) and replace the helloworld example with [my code](https://github.com/gumartinm/SparkForFun/blob/01e9273ffe6a017971ed7ec035f9287dff98f872/keytool/src/sun/security/tools/keytool/KeytoolWithoutPasswordLimits.java).

Comment: We tried eclipse, same idea. Eventually we found the -XDignore.symbol.file which allowed compilation of just the 1 file we needed with a tiny tweak. In the end that was the quicker way to get it working. The commandline was quite helpful in that regard, but it did require some extensive googling.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the above fail you can try cracking it. Related question: [Android - Forgot keystore password. Can I decrypt keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894987/android-forgot-keystore-password-can-i-decrypt-keystore-file)