# How to recover password for jks file which is already available in play store?

Tags: java, android, security, android-keystore, jks

I have already uploaded an app in play store.

I am using android studio 3 for building my application.

[Android - Forgot keystore password. Can I decrypt keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894987/android-forgot-keystore-password-can-i-decrypt-keystore-file) @varun answer i tried all the three scenarios

But not able to get the solution if any other way to recover the password please let me know

**Point to discuss**

> 1.When i searched for `Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password` this key in idea.log.1 i get as encrypted password. `Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=*********,`
>
> 2.my key alias is not encrypted.
>
> 3.based on what i get encrypted password beacuse for my previous project i am not seeing encrypted password my password is visible clearly.
>
> 4.Is there anything to do with choosing signature `v1 and v2` while creating jks file. if so what is the solution?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code of your apk then you can easily get alias and password. follow these steps to recover your keystore original password without  bruteforce. Make sure you don't try to crate a new keystore with that source code otherwise it will store your new password and alias.  try this with your original keystore source code

Select your `list of view` as `project` and open directory and select `.gradle > taskHistory` like this

[image]

Now just open `taskHistory.bin` file and `search` in file `storePassword` or try to find `keyAlias�TestApp�signingConfig.storePassword`

and for `alias` just search `keyAlias` and you will get it

you will find your password here like:

[image]

`test@123` is my password you can find yours , you can find it in next lines maybe it's not found in first line. so try to found at the bottom of page

Hope it's help for you, let me know if it's works for you.

Comment: I could find the storepassword. However i cant find key password. How to search key password?

Comment: by pressing ctrl+f and search keyword storepassword maybe you can find multiple storepassword  keyword keep going at the bottom check updated image.I have updated my answer check it again.

Comment: i found totally 4 `storepassword` in that i got two with diffrent password i tried that but not positive result

Comment: Please make sure that you find it on right directory and Please confirm your alias name and password. please check both .

Comment: yes i am sure of it i am in the same directory as you mentioned above but i found two diffrent password in that directory

Comment: Maybe you tried a new keysore and it will store your new keystore Make sure you don't try to crate a new keystore with that source code otherwise it will store your new password and alias.

Comment: ok but i have not created new keystore or jks i just use the existing one and password i remember that’s it

Comment: Can you please share your taskHistory.bin file? It's working for me on all of my source code that i have use to create keystore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172136/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-sandeep-parish).