# Forget keystore password of my application Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I have lost all the passwords of my application both **keystore password, key alias and key password**. How can I recover it?
I have `.jks` file.

I have formatted my system so there are no logs available of Android Studio.

Comment: check here maybe you will found [your solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604153/how-to-recover-password-for-jks-file-which-is-already-available-in-play-store/50604476?noredirect=1#comment88244599_50604476)

Comment: try this library https://github.com/MaxCamillo/android-keystore-password-recover

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you **can not** recover that now from `.jks` file. You need to create new `keystore` password

Answer (score 1):

if your app is already in the store it won't let you upload the new apk since it will be signed differently, and you won't be able to update it. If your app is not in the store yet, you can create a new keystore and push your app to the store. It's always better to email yourself the keystore key to save it before uploading your apk to the store.

Comment: what is the way to recover password?

Comment: you cant recocer the keystore , this is why backups are so important, sorry

Comment: I have .jks file

Comment: this is like signing a check, if the check is not signed by the person who wrote it, the bank wont accept it

Comment: you cant recover it buddy, sorry

Comment: @ParasArora I have already answered your question. Don't waste time. I have faced the same situation already!

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS IT HELPED ME RECOVER MY PASSWORD**

Search for folder  **.gradle**

under it go to latest folder in my case it is **4.6**

go to **taskHistory** folder

under it open **taskHistory.bin** file

search for **Password** keyword in that file

and you will eventually find your stored password for that keystore file.

refer the screenshots.

[image]

[image]