# unable to generate signed apk android

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my first time using android studio to generate a signed APK. the first time i tried this i randomly filled in the password field and it went through and make the aPK. now that i want to put out a update version of my app, i went to generate it again and i get an error that says the login failed. I have tried making new apks, new eveything when i create it and it still give me that same error about the login being wrong. Is it possible to just redo this and generate a new apk? i even tried deleting all the apk and keys off my computer and it still wont let me generate a new apk. i feel like i may never be able to make this apk and get my project out.

so after deleting all the APK stuff i get this error
keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)

how can it still be asking for that file after deleting everything and makeing a new apk? i have no idea what to do.

so i put that file back , and now i get password verification failed again. god, this thing is a huge mess.

Comment: Have you published your app at play store? If yes, then you have to use the same keystore to update it. Simply generating a new one will not work.

Comment: no , i only generated one to try on my phone.

Comment: If it is just for your use, then create a new keystore

Comment: @Davi  thats exactly what i was trying to do. but when i try to make a new one , it gives me a complier error " password verification failed". its like it keeps trying to use the first one i made. no matter what i do , i get that same compiler error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to this recover your lost keystore password:

- If you have your logs intact, then you can find the password in the Android Studio log files : Go to ~/Library/Logs -> AndroidStudio ->idea.log.1 and search for Search for "Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password" and you can see the key password.
- You can retrieve the password from the in your .gradle directory. Look in .gradle\2.4\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin. This doesn't seem to work for newer versions of Gradle (2.10 and above).
- Use AndroidKeystoreBrute to guess or bruteforce your password as per [Alex Kutsko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779723/3847306) above.

[Solution link](http://techzog.com/development/android/retrieve-saved-keystore-password-android-studio/)

[Got this from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38567782/6084751)